# SQL join two tables from two conditions in just one

Tags: sql, sql-server

In Visual Studio I have two SQL expressions but I want to combine them into just one so I can easily analyze the results in same table. For now I have two tables side by side and manually compare the data.

Expression 1 will test if employee has listed has active or not: Those who are active will show in table.

| Employee |
| --- |
| Employee 1 |
| Employee 2 |
| Employee 3 |
| Employee 4 |
| Employee 5 |
| Employee 6 |

Code:

```
where AG.active=1
order by name
```

Expression 2 will check the operation that employee is doing and when it started.

| Employee | Operation | Time | Client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 2 | Washing | 2021-04-22 14:00:00 | Client 1 |
| Employee 3 | Cleaning | 2021-04-22 14:10:00 | Client 2 |
| Employee 4 | Drying | 2021-04-22 14:34:00 | Client 10 |
| Employee 6 | Delivering | 2021-04-22 15:01:00 | Client 15 |

Code:

```
SELECT ag.name, bi.job as 'Operation', bi.data as 'Time', bo.client as 'Client'
FROM bi
        INNER JOIN bo 
            ON bi.aobr = bo.obr
        INNER JOIN AG 
            ON ag.no=bi.no
WHERE  (bi.dos = 33 OR bi.dos = 71) AND (YEAR(bi.data2) = 1900) AND (AG.activef=1)
```

So I want to produce a table where it lists all the employee that fill expression 1 condition and then it will show, for employee that are working, what they are doing. Employee that are not doing anything will show the same but column "Operation" and "Time" empty.
Expected result:

| Employee | Operation | Time | Client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee 1 |  |  |  |
| Employee 2 | Washing | 2021-04-22 14:00:00 | Client 1 |
| Employee 3 | Cleaning | 2021-04-22 14:10:00 | Client 2 |
| Employee 4 | Drying | 2021-04-22 14:34:00 | Client 10 |
| Employee 5 |  |  |  |
| Employee 6 | Delivering | 2021-04-22 15:01:00 | Client 15 |

With this I can easily see who are the employee that are working and those who aren't doing anything, at least to software that writes information in SQL database.

It's possible to do what I want?
I hope I explain what I have and what i want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to first query the Employee table to get all the active Employees and then do a LEFT JOIN on the bi and bo tables. So something like this:

```
SELECT ag.name, 
        bi.job as 'Operation', 
        bi.data as 'Time', 
        bo.client as 'Client'
FROM AG 
    LEFT JOIN bi
            ON ag.no=bi.no AND (bi.dos = 33 OR bi.dos = 71) AND (YEAR(bi.data2) = 1900) AND (AG.activef=1)
    LEFT JOIN bo 
            ON bi.aobr = bo.obr
WHERE ag.active = 1
order by ag.name
```

Comment: He said he also wants to display employees who are not active, so the `ag.active = 1` condition should be moved from `WHERE` to the `ON` part of the left join to the `bi` table

Comment: Yeah I was not sure about what he meant by - 'lists all the employee that fill expression 1 condition and then...'. If he wants only active = 1 in the entire list then he should keep it this way. If not move it to the ON.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing, but if the last table is his desired output then what I said should be done.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear to explain. On the one hand I tried to explain everything but I also tried not to create a very long text and it may not have been clear.
What I meant with "lists all the employee that fill expression 1 condition and then" is that all want to list all employee that are active, in this case it's the first table.

I will try that code.

Answer (score 0):

The below query should help you. SO basically from AG you are taking all active employees( ag.active = 1) and then for all those active employees you are displaying their work task, time, and client name. The LEFT JOIN helps to pull all records from LEFT table ( i.e. all active employees records from table AG) and pull matching records from the other 2 tables if a match exists on the join column.

```
SELECT AG.name, 
 bi.job as 'Operation', 
 bi.data as 'Time', 
 bo.client as 'Client'
 FROM AG 
 LEFT JOIN bi ON AG.no = bi.no
             AND (bi.dos = 33 OR bi.dos = 71) 
             AND YEAR(bi.data2) = 1900
 LEFT JOIN bo ON bi.aobr = bo.obr
 WHERE AG.active = 1
```